# Inverse Mute Group for Yamaha LS9?

Tags: mixing

Is it possible to automatically mute an output channel on the LS9 when a particular input channel is turned on?

This is for a radio studio.  I'd like the omni out that I have going to the studio speakers to be turned off when one of the two microphone inputs are turned on, so that I don't pick up music and such in the mics when people forget to turn them down.

If I can't find a way to do it on the board itself, I will probably just resort to writing some simple software that listens for the MIDI when the channels are turned on, and sends the proper MIDI for turning off the output.

Answer (score 2):

Brad,

I have a similar situation. I work at a TV station that uses an LS9. Studio speakers need to be muted when mics are turned on. I have a temporary work around that I'm using now. I simply send a mix-minus feed to the studio, but a full feed to the transmitter. It's not an elegant solution, but it works.

I'm looking into a midi-to-relay method because the talent here is used to hearing a relay "click" to know their mics are hot. I also want to have remote starts for some of the audio playback machines when certain channels are turned on. I'm probably going to try using a MIDI Solutions R8 8-output MIDI-controlled Relay Array. I found it at http://www.midisolutions.com/prodr8.htm.

It's been a while since you posed your question. I'm quite interested in knowing if you've found a working solution?

Bob

Comment: I never did find a solid solution. I left the station not long after this post. I think if I were to implement now, I would go the software route. Come to think of it, I have the exact same issue on my X32...

Answer (score 1):

I thought of solution which not exactly what you want, but I think good enough:

Send your microphones to their own MIX (mic mix). Set up really drastic compressor with longer release to your output mix (to speakers) and set this mic mix as source. This will cause that any sound coming through microphones will really compress the output.

Now I realized one drawback, you will have to have mute group with mics and mic mix in it and mute them all by user defined key, because mics are being sent into mix even if they are muted.

It may be seem complex to setup, but it can be used relatively easy.